# Api Platform incorrect context response with custom operation

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm using API Platform for a project and I have a problem with the custom operation. The response of my action is not realy the output I expected. In fact, some elements of the context is not exact for my request.

Her is an example of my code

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

...

/**
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "list_conversation"={"method"="GET", "path"="/users/{id}/conversations", "controller"="App\Action\Conversation\ConversationByUser", "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or object == user"}
 *})
 */
class User
{
   ...
}
```

```
<?php
namespace App\Action\Conversation;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\ConversationUser;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

class ConversationByUser
{
    /**
     * @var RegistryInterface
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * ConversationByUser constructor.
     * @param RegistryInterface $registry
     */
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function __invoke(string $id)
    {
        $emUser = $this->registry->getManagerForClass(User::class);

        $user = $emUser->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy([
            'id' => $id
        ]);

        $emConversationUser = $this->registry->getManagerForClass(ConversationUser::class);

        $conversationUsers = $emConversationUser->getRepository(ConversationUser::class)->findBy([
            'user' => $user
        ]);

        $conversations = [];

        /** @var ConversationUser $conversationUser */
        foreach ($conversationUsers as $conversationUser) {
            $conversations[] = $conversationUser->getConversation();
        }

        return $conversations;
    }
}
```

I expect this output

```
    "@context": "/contexts/Conversation",
    "@id": "/users/{id}/conversations",
    "@type": "hydra:Collection",
    "hydra:member": [],
    "hydra:totalItems": 0,
    "hydra:search": {
       ...
    }
```

but the actual output is

```
    "@context": "/contexts/User",
    "@id": "/users",
    "@type": "hydra:Collection",
    "hydra:member": [],
    "hydra:totalItems": 0,
    "hydra:search": {
       ...
    }
```

We can see the difference with **@context** and **@id**

Thanks for your help

Ps:
I try the marv255 solution, the @context change correctly, but the @id is still false.

Comment: Your `ApiResource` is linked to `User` entity, so that `context` and `id` is for `User`. If you want `Conversation` `context` you should add this action to `Conversation` entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it was possible 4 years ago, but with apiplatform 3.0 you can change the itemUriTemplate :

> To do so, use the itemUriTemplate option only available on GetCollection and Post operations:

```
#[GetCollection(
    uriTemplate: '/users/{userId}/conversations',
    itemUriTemplate: '/users/{userId}/conversations/{id}',
    controller: 'App\Action\Conversation\ConversationByUser'/*, ... */)
 ]
#[Post(itemUriTemplate: '/users/{userId}/conversations/{id}'/*, ... */)]
#[Get(uriTemplate: '/users/{userId}/conversations/{id}'/*, ... */)]
class Conversation
{
```

source: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#defining-which-operation-to-use-to-generate-the-iri